# For performance, one multi-value field or four individual fields?

Tags: 8, performance

I have a node content type that needs to store four different `int` values:

- Score A
- Score B
- Score C
- Score D

Each node of the content type always has all four `int` values.

I could store this one of two ways:

1. Store all four scores in a single `Integer` field that is limited to four values. (Set Score A to the 0 position, Score B to the 1 position, and so on.) (One field in total)
2. Store each of the four scores as its own `Integer` field. (Four fields in total)

From a usability perspective, it's easier to have four fields because it's more obvious where each score is, and configuring views is easier.

However, from the perspective of performance, which is better?

Comment: This question cannot be answered, too many unknown parameters. You can only measure performance for a specific query on a specific environment, and we don't know the query/storage engine/config/etc you'll be using. The only reliable answer is test it yourself on your own environment with the query you'll be using.

Comment: I agree with @Hudri, most times you would simply configure these four fields and never got into any performance problems. When you do, then a custom field type with four properties all in one database table would be the most efficient.

Comment: @Hudri Ok, thanks.  I thought there might be a general recommendation for this, but I see now that there is not.

Comment: I agree with @4k4's general recommendation: Just don't care :-) If you expect **really huge** traffic and **really huge** data sets, then a custom field type = one single DB table with 4 integer value columns sounds like a good start. But it still ends with "do tests on your own system".